# Internationalization is not working for spring reactive that is also when using flatmap which is asynchronous

Tags: spring, spring-webflux, configuration-files, http-accept-language, spring-internationalization

By passing Locale field to the validateExistingShipments method ...it is

Comment: You shouldn't use the `LocaleContextHolder` in a reactive environment, simply because it isn't meant to be used there. Instead you should use the `ServerWebExchange.getLocaleContext` instead. Next to that you shouldn't be resolving the messages (imho) as you are currently doing, instead write an exception handler, which then can resolve the message based on the locale set in the `ServerWebExchange` which you can access from there. This instead of littering your code with a `MessageSource`.

Comment: In my project we are using LocalContextHolder.getLocale everywhere  . so I does not replace it now .so I need changes only in configuration and filter class which should work in asynchronous methods or flatmap etc..

Comment: `LocaleContextHolder` is based on threadlocal and that isn't the suitable mechanism to use in a reactive application for various reasons. If your code is litered with the code you already have you are doing it wrong anyway (imho) you shouldn't have that leaking into everything, as well as the `MessageSource`.

Comment: what approach I need to follow for reactive environment  @M.Deinum